# Proving non-collinear points of a triangle

Tags: geometry

My question is as follows: Let triangle $ABC$ be a triangle in $R^2$, and let $U$ be any point of $R^2$ that is not
collinear with any two of the points $A, B, C$. Let the Lines BC and AU meet
at $P, CA$ and $BU$ meet at $Q$, and $AB$ and $CU$ meet at $R$. Prove that $P, Q, R$
cannot be collinear.

I would like someone to point me in the right direction because I have no idea where to start this proof. Thank you very much!

Comment: I recommend you make a sketch and attach it to your question. A good sketch is 50% of solving a geometry problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algebraic approach. For lack of context in your question, it's hard to day what approach would be suitable to your background.

Using barycentric coordinates you have $A=[1:0:0]$, $B=[0:1:0]$ and $C=[0:0:1]$. You also have $U=[x:y:z]$ with $x,y,z\neq 0$ due to the non-collinear condition. If you don't use homogeneous coordinates you also have $x+y+z=1$, but personally I prefer homogeneous where this constraint is not needed.

Points on line $BC$ are linar combinations of $B$ and $C$, i.e. points where the first coordinate is zero. Likewise points on $AU$ has linear combinations of $A$ and $U$. So the point of intersection can be described as $P=U-xA=yB+zC=[0:y:z]$. To dehomogenize you'd have to divide coordinates by $y+z$ but I'll stay homogeneous.

By the same argument $Q=[x:0:z]$ and $R=[x:y:0]$. These three points are collinear iff their determinant is zero (for reasons I'll explain in a second). So you compute

$$\det(P,Q,R)=\begin{vmatrix}0&x&x\\y&0&y\\z&z&0\end{vmatrix}=2xyz$$

A product is zero iff one of its factors is zero, and we stated at the beginning that $x,y,z\neq 0$.

So why this determinant to check for collinearity? Because if say $R$ were on line $PQ$ then you could write $R=\lambda P+\mu Q$ i.e. the three vectors were linearily dependent. Determinant to check for linear dependence is a common tool in linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "pure geometry" approach.

The figure formed by $A,B,C,U$ and $P,Q,R$ (left part of picture below) is very classical ; it is called a "complete quadrilateral".

[image]

I don't know if you a have a background in projective geometry ; if such is the case, you should know that this alignment property is invariant through any projective transformation, in particular any transformation $(T)$ mapping $ABCU$ onto a rectangle (as displayed on the figure) ; in this way the images $P'$ and $R'$ of $P$ and $R$ resp. belong to the line at infinity $(L)$ whereas the image $Q'$ of $Q$, which is the rectangle's center, remains at finite distance ; in particular $Q'$ does not belong to $(L)$. Thus $P',Q',R'$ aren't aligned ; therefore $P,Q,R$ aren't either.